# How to remove a specific part of a string in Postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a column in postgres database called `pid` that looks like this:

```
set1/2019-10-17/ASR/20190416832-ASR.pdf
set1/2019-03-15/DEED/20190087121-DEED.pdf
set1/2021-06-22/DT/20210376486-DT.pdf
```

I want to remove everything after the last dash "-" including the dash itself. So expected results:

```
set1/2019-10-17/ASR/20190416832.pdf
set1/2019-03-15/DEED/20190087121.pdf
set1/2021-06-22/DT/20210376486.pdf
```

I've looked into replace() and split_part() functions but still can't figure out how
to do this. Please advise.

Comment: Show us your attempt so we can see where we could assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^(.*)-[^-]+(\.\w+)$', '\1\2') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

The regex used above captures the column value before the last dash in `\1`, and the extension in `\2`.  It then builds the output using `\1\2` as the replacement.

Here is a [working regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sYG8Xn/1).

Comment: What is the `'\1\2'` part after the comma in REGEXP_REPLACE()?

Comment: @amnesic `\1` refers to the first capture group, which is `(.*)`.  The `\2` is the second capture group and is `(\.\w+)`.